# How to exclude axis when scaling just with the mouse

Tags: shortcut

I know I can do this by holding shift and then typing the letter of the axis I want to be excluded. However, I really like how I can scale on one axis by hitting "s" and then just use the mouse wheel to click and move in the direction I want to scale.  However, I haven't found a way to exclude an axis using this method.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the mouse only, but after pressing  <kbd>S</kbd>, while the scaling operator is active you can press <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> to constraint to an axis, depending on the direction the mouse is pointing.

Similarly you can also press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> to exclude the same axis.

[image]